# most efficient way to populate composite class

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I just want to get some opinions on the most efficient and quickest way to populate my composite class using the EF4.0. I have a parent class which has a structure similar to the class below. It mirrors my database structure.

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   ........
   public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }
   public IList<Account> Workspace { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   ......
}

public class Account
{
   public string SortCode { get; set; }
   public IList<string> TransactionHistory {get; set;}
   ......
}
```

So, at this moment in time I pull back all the 'Persons' from the EF and I loop through each of them and populate the Address and Accounts for each. Lazy loading is enabled, so I have to encapsulate all my loops in the using statement or my Accounts will be empty when I try to iterator through them. So, can I disable lazy loading for this call only or should approach the population of my list of persons in another manner.

```
using (var entities = new PersonEntities())
{
    var dbPeople = (from person in entities.Persons
                    select person).ToList();

    foreach(var person in dbPeople)
    {
        foreach(var account in person.Accounts)
        {
           // In here I populate my 'Person' business object account and add it to my collection to return.
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you're going to include the relation keeping the LazyLoading enabled. You can do this for the query using the Include method:

```
using (var entities = new PersonEntities())
{
    var dbPeople = entities.Persons.Include("Accounts").ToList();

    foreach(var person in dbPeople)
    {
        //Do nothing with Accounts if the relation is mapped correct
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Also you can disable LazyLoading for the created PersonEntities instance's lifetime:

```
using (var entities = new PersonEntities())
{
        entities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        //...
}
```